# selectOneRadio with action immediately after click

Tags: java, jsf, seam

This should be easy for a pro:

I am using JSF/Facelets/Seam and am trying to display radiobuttons. Then, after the user has clicked on one of the buttons, the value should be saved and the user redirected to another page immediately (i.e. with no needed click on a submit button).

The radio button works, but not the forwarding.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can indeed use Richfaces to add an [a4j:support component](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/support.jsf):

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.myValue}" ...>
    ...
    <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{myBean.doSomething}"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

In your Java code:

```
public String doSomething() {
    // Your code goes here...
    ...
    // Now, we move to the new page.
    return "some-outcome";
}
```

However, if you cannot (or do not want) to add a new library, you can do this by the old way:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.myValue}" ... onclick="this.form.submit();" valueChangeListener="#{myBean.doSomething}">
    ...
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

This code will submit the form where the radio button are contained when the onclick Javascript event is detected. On the server side, the action doSomething will be executed.
In this method, you can make a navigation rule to be executed:

```
public void doSomething(ValueChangeEvent evt) {
    // Your code goes here...
    ...
    // Now, we move to another page...
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    NavigationHandler navigation = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    navigation.handleNavigation(context, "", "some-outcome");
}
```

where some-outcome is an outcome defined in a navigation rule in your faces-config.xml.

Answer (score 1):

With JSF 2.0 you can do the following

```
<h:selectOneRadio ...
...
    <f:ajax event="change" render="@form" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```